# how to use EM::Synchrony::Multi with redis?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, concurrency, eventmachine, em-synchrony

I am trying to perform several redis queries in parallel, but getting an error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/em-synchrony-1.0.2/lib/em-synchrony.rb:53:in `resume':
dead fiber called (FiberError)
```

here is the code:

```
require 'em-synchrony'
require 'redis/connection/synchrony'
require 'redis'

redis = EM::Synchrony::ConnectionPool.new(size: 4) do
  Redis.new
end

EM.synchrony do
  multi = EM::Synchrony::Multi.new
  multi.add :a, redis.alpush('foo', 1)
  multi.add :b, redis.alpush('foo', 2)
  res = multi.perform

  p res

  EM.stop
end
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Eventmachine specific `em-hiredis` gem instead of the default driver.

`gem install em-hiredis`

```
require 'em-synchrony'
require 'em-synchrony/em-hiredis'

redis = EM::Synchrony::ConnectionPool.new(size: 4) do
          EM::Hiredis.new
        end
```

Anywhere `EM::Synchrony` is used, it is usually suggested to use the synchrony specific library shipped with `em-synchrony`. That is why the statement `em-synchrony/em-hiredis` and not `require em-synchrony`.